# actionbar and layout in coordinatorlayout are overlapping each other

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using coordinatorlayout in my android application and is defined as following

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
                                             tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test"/>
```

The test layout is `LinearLayout` which has a further Views

The problem is that the actionbar is overlapping the content of the Test Layout

Could this because of the themes ? (which i personally dont feel ) but then not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try this,

Theme is not really a problem.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: everything will remain the same but you need to add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your include layout. It will work as expected.

Comment: oh ok, even i was sure (pretty sure) that theme is not an issue. but then i have not made any other change... @valentino had pointed the same thing but rather than in the test.xml it was supposed to be added to the include tag

yes it worked !

Comment: Happy coding !!

Answer (score 3):

Try to add in your TestLayout xml definition the following line:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**Update**

To fix your problem, you can simply remove the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` from your `include` tag, so your `include` will look like this:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:id="@+id/test"/>
```

Alternatively, as suggested correctly below from @santosh kumar, you can move the line above from the LinearLayout definition to the include definition.

Comment: its already present .. the header is as follows `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">`

Comment: layout parameter "layout_marginTop" will be ignored unless both  "layout_width" and "layout_height" are also specified on <include> tag - Documentation. Also "app:layout_behavior" will be ignored from the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

use marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" to the included layout